# Retrieving function app settings on commandline includes removed items

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm downloading my app settings via a batch file. I use this command:

```
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings MyFuncApp
```

It works great. However I noticed that if I delete a key/value pair in Azure, save it, and then redownload the app settings, it still includes the deleted pair. I tried this a few more times, and each time, the deleted values still show up when I download the app settings. Is this a known issue? Or is there something I'm missing in regards to downloading the app settings?

Comment: It doesn't do a merge, just adds or updates local values to match Azure, but if you have a value locally that doesn't exist in Azure, it'll just leave it alone. That might be what's happening if you pulled the settings once and then deleted the value and executed the same command without deleting `local.settings.json`.

Comment: That was it, didn't notice the local file. Thanks! Not sure how to mark that as the answer since I don't see an option to.

Comment: I was just checking to make sure that was the issue not some other bug maybe. I added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cli doesn't do a merge for these settings. You can take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/blob/04c06d7a629853429c464ede3c347f75ddbb0453/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/AzureActions/FetchAppSettingsAction.cs#L28-L33), but basically it just grabs the app settings from Azure and  adds or updates local values to match Azure. If you have a value locally that doesn't exist in Azure, it'll just leave it alone.

You can either delete it manually from the file `local.settings.json` or you can use this command `func settings delete <settingName>`